# Using variable in $_POST

Tags: php, post

I have an HTML form collecting data in which I have a series of fields that repeat for 18 rows (eg name1, name2, names, etc).  This data is then passed into a PHP script using POST that processes that data.
What I would like to be able to do is create a loop that increments a counter so that the name field can be regenerated the required number of times.  For example, a loop that does:-

```
$x=1; 
$processName = 'name' . $x; 
$nameField=$_POST['$processName']; 
printf("%s<br>\n",$nameField);
$x++;
```

This repeats and outputs each of the name fields from the initial form.
Can this be done?

Comment: Use a for loop?

Comment: Yes I co do a for loop,  but how do I reference the required name field (eg $_POST['$nameField'] using a variable.

Comment: Here is something a little more specific:

$SQL = "update Teams set ladder=".$pos.",played=".$_POST['played1'].",win=".$_POST['win1'].",loss=".$_POST['loss1'].",draw=".$_POST['draw1'].",percent=".$_POST['pcnt1']." where id=".$_POST['id1'];
HOw do I set a variable to replace $_POST['played1'] so that it can increment the required number of time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
foreach ($_POST as $param_key => $param_val) {
    echo "name" . $param_val . "<br />\n";
}
```